# "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate" request attribute does not return CA certs

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a requirement where a single web app, which has multiple web services, needs SSL configured. But only one web service should have mutual SSL and rest have to be on one-way SSL.

For this, I have used:

```
 <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="want"
 disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
 port="8443" keystoreFile="somefolder\some-KeyStore.store" keystorePass="changeit"
 protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
 secure="true" sslProtocol="SSL" 
 truststoreFile="somefolder\some-trustStore.jks"
 truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="Changeit"/>
```

And in the code I use below code in a filter to a service URL:

```
X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) request
                    .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

This checks if the service that needs mutual SSL gets a certificate that is valid. So when that URL gets called, the servlet filter checks for cert.

But the problem is that this works only for self-signed certs; when I use CA signed certs, the above scriptlet returns null. (i.e., no certs)

The cert algorithms are RSA and DSA types; is there any significance of this or the type of keyStores and trustStores.

Please let me know if I am missing anything, or if I need to use any other code for CA signed certs. I really need CA certs in the requests.

Comment: Have you added the CA's certificate in your truststore (truststoreFile="somefolder\some-trustStore.jks") file?

Comment: yes, I have, The same SSL flow works with self signed certs but doesn't work with mutual ssl.

Comment: My guess is that you are missing to pass the client certificate (p12) from the web service client.

Comment: I use soapUI for this purpose and when I use the self signed keyStore (selfSigned.store) to pass certificate it works, but for CA signed cert I use .p12 keyStore and then it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the Input,

But I figured it out.
I did not import the cert chain in the TrustStore initially, and I just had the CA cert there. Once I configured the CA certs, keystore and trustStore properly, it fixed the issue.

It worked initially with self-signed certs because self signed certs don't have cert chains.