# The javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate property returns null

Tags: java, ssl, client-certificates, tomee-7

in a `ContainerRequestFilter` i am trying to read the client's **self signed** certificate, and i am getting null.

Java:

`X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) requestContext.getProperty("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");`

Tomee server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https"
    secure="true" maxPostSize="100000"
    >
    <SSLHostConfig
    certificateVerification="optionalNoCA"
    truststoreFile="/my/java/cacerts"
    truststorePassword="changeit"
    >
    <Certificate
            certificateKeyAlias="myalias"
            certificateKeystoreFile="/my/keystore/filepath"
            certificateKeystorePassword="changeit"
            certificateKeystoreType="JKS" >
    </Certificate>
    </SSLHostConfig>
```

What configuration am I missing?

Comment: getProperty or getAttribute, Also look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486300/javax-servlet-request-x509certificate-request-attribute-does-not-return-ca-cer?rq=1

Comment: @TechFree it is a `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext`, there is no `getAttribute()`.