# Problem reading client certificate in JDK 17

Tags: java, java-11, client-certificates, java-17, payara

I have been trying to read a client certificate in a simple WebFilter. The code was working till JDK 11. But, when I tried to upgrade server to JDK 17 it has stopped reading the client request.

I am trying to read the client certificate provided in a request using following statement:

```
X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

As well as this (Working with JDK 11)

```
X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

Curl request:

```
curl --cacert server-cert.pem --cert client-cert.pem --key client-key.pem https://localhost:8181/st/echo --insecure
```

It's retuning null with JDK 17: `request.getAttribute("jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate")` 
and here as well:
`request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")`

I am using Server:

- Payara 5 with
- JDK 11 (Working)
- JDK 17 (Not Working)

Logs for SSL, Handshake debugging:

```
[2023-10-31T07:20:51.257+0100] [Payara 5.2022.4] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid:
_ThreadID=94 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(1)] [timeMillis: 1698733251257] [levelValue: 1000] [[  
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(1)|2023-10-31
07:20:51.255 CET|CertificateRequest.java:635|Produced
CertificateRequest handshake message ( "CertificateRequest": {  
"certificate types": [ecdsa_sign, rsa_sign, dss_sign]   "supported
signature algorithms": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256,
ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, ed25519, ed448,
rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, ] } )
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(1)|2023-10-31
07:20:51.256 CET|ServerHelloDone.java:97|Produced ServerHelloDone
handshake message ( <empty> ) ]]
.........

[2023-10-31T07:20:51.268+0100] [Payara 5.2022.4] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid:
_ThreadID=96 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(3)] [timeMillis: 1698733251268] [levelValue: 1000] [[  
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|06|http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(3)|2023-10-31
07:20:51.268 CET|Finished.java:459|Produced server Finished handshake
message ( "Finished": {   "verify data": {
    0000: F9 74 05 86 F7 A5 08 9E   75 49 F0 09    }'} ) ]]

[2023-10-31T07:20:51.274+0100] [Payara 5.2022.4] [INFO] [] [] [tid:
_ThreadID=98 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(5)] [timeMillis: 1698733251274] [levelValue: 800] [[   No client
certificate found in the request.]]
 
[2023-10-31T07:20:51.277+0100] [Payara 5.2022.4] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid:
_ThreadID=94 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(1)] [timeMillis: 1698733251277] [levelValue: 1000] [[  
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(1)|2023-10-31
07:20:51.277 CET|Alert.java:238|Received alert message ( "Alert": {  
"level"      : "warning",   "description": "close_notify" } )
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486300/javax-servlet-request-x509certificate-request-attribute-does-not-return-ca-cer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351472/getattributejavax-servlet-request-x509certificate-not-set-spring-cxf-jetty

Comment: @tgdavies it's not useful as I have tried that and as I mentioned I had same certificate, same code  and same server. I have just changed the JDK and it has stopped working.

Comment: Same server truststore?

Comment: Yes @user207421

Comment: OK so you need to set [`javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug) at either end, or both, and show us the part of the log where the server requested a certificate and the client sent one.

Comment: @WasifKirmani don't add details in comments, [edit] your post to work those details [into your question](/help/how-to-ask) as information that you've gathered while debugging/(re)searching the problem.

Comment: Come off it. That's not what I asked for. I asked for 'the part of the log where the server requested a certificate and the client sent one'. There should be a `CertificateRequest` message from the server, and a `Certificate` message from the client. And don't post it as comments. You can see for yourself that it's totally illegible. Edit it into your question.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Unless you have forgotten to include it again, that log shows that the client didn't send a certificate. That means that either it doesn't have one at all, or it doesn't have one that matches what the server specified in the `CertificateRequest`: which in turn would support the contention that the server's truststore wasn't updated.

Comment: But, if this is the case then how it's working with jdk 11. As it works fine when I start the server with JDK 11 and fails when I start the same server with JDK 17.

Comment: Because JDK 11 has a different default truststore. It would be instructive to compare the `Certificate Request` messages sent by both configurations.